# Conditional operations in function composition

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, function-composition

How do I stop or branch a composition based on some logical condition?

For example. Suppose I have the following code:

```
compose(
  operation4
  operation3,
  operation2,
  operation1
)(myStuff);
```

Or even something like

```
myStuff
 .map(operation1)
 .map(operation2)
 .map(operation3)
 .map(operation4)
```

And I only want operations 3 and 4 to be executed if myStuff fulfils some condition.

How do I implement that (specially in JavaScript)?

Do I have to create two smaller compositions and have a separate if statement or is there a way to have the condition within the composition?

Could Monads solve my problem? If so, how?

Comment: That probably depends on the framework you are using. If you're using your own compose function, you could probably just extend it to allow conditions (e.g. `myStuff.map(a).if(b).map(c)`). If you're using an external framework, you might need to split it into two parts.

Comment: If you want to stop the composition as soon as a condition isn't met, you can apply `Either` as a monad (with its `chain` method). If you just want to omit the function that causes the unfulfilled condition, you can apply `Either` as a applicative functor (with its `ap` method) or use a ternary function operator like in Georg's answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to do `[myStuff].filter(predicate).map(fx1).map(fx2)` or use any other stream library for that matter?

Comment: @LUH3417 The `Either` monad option sounds like the kind of thing I am looking for, but I am not very knowledgeable of Monads yet. Would you mind answering with an implementation of how that would look like?

Comment: Um, I am not so sure anymore whether `Either` is suitable in this case. If I understand you correctly, you don't want to check the condition against each function but only for the 3rd and 4th one. I need to think about it more closely.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the `Maybe`/`Option` monad, but the operations 3 and 4 would depend on the return value of operation 2, not on `myStuff`. So yes, you better use an explicit `if`-statement or ternary operator.

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni I don't know if you are still interested in this somehow old question. Anyway, I've gained new insights regarding composition and rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 9):

A simple but practical approach is to have a function like `when(cond, f)` which executes `f` (which can in turn be a composition) only if `cond(x)` returns true:

```js
_do = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x);
_when = (cond, f) => x => cond(x) ? f(x) : x;


// example

add3 = x => x + 3;
add5 = x => x + 5;
add9 = x => x + 9;


pipe = _do(
    add3,
    add5,
    _when(x => x > 20, _do(add9))
)


console.log(pipe(30))
console.log(pipe(1))
```

Comment: Passing a single function to `do` doesn't appear to be useful.

Comment: Naming that function `do` is a bit confusing, one might expect that it does monadic (Kleisli) composition like in Haskell (where your function is more like `appEndo . foldMap Endo`). `compose` might be a better name.

Answer (score 3):

### Exit a composition prematurely

This is at least possible, but I think it isn't a good idea. Function composition is meant to behave like a single function. It is an atomic operation. Therefore, premature exiting is not provided out of the box.

Let us take a step back. The composition of `n` functions is a classic reduction:

```js
// generic functions

const foldr = f => acc => xs =>
 xs.reduceRight((acc, x, i) => f(x) (acc, i), acc);

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const I = x => x;

const inc = x => x + 1;

// derived function

const compn = foldr(comp) (I);


// run

console.log(
  compn([inc, inc, inc, inc]) (0) // 4
);
```

`compn` produces a similar computation like:

```js
const I = x => x;

const inc = x => x + 1;

const computation = x => inc(inc(inc(inc(I(x)))));

console.log(
  computation(0) // 4
);
```

If we want to exit the composition prematurely, we have to adapt both, the iterative algorithm (`foldr`) and the composition (`compn`):

```js
// generic functions

const foldrk = f => acc => xs => {
  const next = (i, acc) => i < 0
   ? acc
   : f(xs[i], i) (acc) (acc => next(i - 1, acc));

  return next(xs.length - 1, acc);
};

const I = x => x;

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const inc = x => x + 1;

const lt = y => x => x < y;


// derived function

compWhile = pred => foldrk(f => acc => k => k(
  x => pred(x) 
   ? comp(acc) (f) (x) 
   : x
)) (I);


// run

console.log(
  compWhile(lt(2)) ([inc, inc, inc, inc]) (0) // 2
);
```

The composition proceeds as long as the current return value is lower than two. The code is hard to reason about. I don't even try to explain it (it is not worth the effort). Anyway, `compWhile` produces the following computation:

```js
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const I = x => x;

const inc = x => x + 1;

const lt = y => x => x < y;

const lt2 = lt(2);

const computation = x => lt2(x) 
 ? comp(x => lt2(x)
  ? comp(x => lt2(x)
   ? comp(x => lt2(x)
    ? comp(I) (inc) (x)
    : x) (inc) (x)
   : x) (inc) (x)
  : x) (inc) (x)
 : x;


console.log(
  computation(0) // 2
);
```

### Branching a composition

Just split the composition up into smaller compositions, which represent the desired branches. If you try to compose conditional functions, you'll inevitably end up with unreadable code.

If you have merely a simple condition and you don't want to split your composition, at least make the branching as explicit as possible, for instance with the conditional operator `:?`:

```js
const foldr = f => acc => xs =>
 xs.reduceRight((acc, x, i) => f(x) (acc, i), acc);

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const I = x => x;

const inc = x => x + 1;

const compn = foldr(comp) (I);


console.log(
  compn([x => x >= 2 ? x : inc(x), inc, inc]) (0) // 2
);
```

### Conclusion

Function composition is an atomic operation. Don't try to exit prematurely or to branch from within the composition.

Comment: `const compn = flip(foldr(apply))` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting the question to certain degree, but this sounds like the kind of thing you could do with arrays or streams, for example, with reactive streams or any other similar library.

```
var myStuff = "one";
[myStuff]
  .filter(text => text.length <= 3)
  .map(text => text.split('').reverse().join(''))
  .map(text => text.toUpperCase())
  .forEach(text => console.log(text)); //prints ENO
```

Or using a stream library like [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS).

```
Rx.Observable.of("one","two","three")
            .filter(text => text.length <= 3)
            .map(text => text.split('').reverse().join(''))
            .map(text => text.toUpperCase())
            .forEach(text => console.log(text)); //prints ENO, OWT
```

And both the examples above data won't flow to reversing and uppercasing operations unless the filtering condition is satisfied, which seems to be what you're asking.

Although this is so obvious that I have the feeling your question is probably about something else. In either case I hope this contributes to the discussion.

Comment: The OP asks for conditional function composition, not iterative algorithms.

Comment: @LUH3417 Streams are not iterative algorithms. Also, I focused in what the OP says s/he wants to achieve, not on his/her idea on how it is supposed to be accomplished. So for me the matter here is whether this solves the problem or if the problem is wrongfully stated or I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: A stream is an asynchronous, lazily produced sequence on which you apply iterative algorithms. This has nothing in common with function composition. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo What I am looking for would be something where, using your example, I would only execute the last two chained operations (`map` and `forEach`) if the result of the first two operations (`filter` and `map`) fulfilled some condition. Is there any way to do that without breaking this chain in two?

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni Doesn't it already do that? Once you place a filter in the chain, the rest of the operations below it won't be executed unless the filter predicate is satisfied.

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni After 4 years, by what method have you decided to use for branching logic in function composition?

Comment: @Cancri The perfect answer is something called Functors. in JavaScript they are unfortunately not very obvious. There is a good explanation using JavaScript here https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide/blob/master/ch08.md

Answer (score 0):

Just analyze your **someObject** after each step. Example with condition callback, but you can implement this check in different ways.

```
function compose(...fns) {
    return function (result, conditionCallback) {
        for (var i = fns.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            result = fns[i].call(this, result);

            // Run here condition check if provided.
            if (conditionCallback && conditionCallback(result) === false) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
};

compose(...functionList)(someObject, function(obj) {
    return obj.prop !== someValue;
});
```

PS: I hope to understand right, what did you mean under "composition".

PPS: Example uses ES6 features, but downgrading it to ES5 is very simple.